# Переназначение боковых кнопок мыши(конфликт со стоковыми действиями)

Tags: c#, python, mouse-event, autoit

Хочу написать прогу типа logitech options(переназначение клавиш) главной особенностью, которой будут жесты и возможность работы с любой мышкой.

Пока писал в idle  использовал ctypes и боковую кнопки мыши, где они не задействованы и я мог добавлять свои действия. А вот в chrome, мои действия также выполняются, но у них есть и **стандартные действия назад/вперед**, что сильно мешает мне! Как я могу скрыть нажатия кнопок от других программ или **заблокировать их действия**?

Какую библиотеку или функцию лучше использовать, чтобы это сделать?
Я использую этот код чтобы отследить нажатие кнопок:

```
from ctypes import windll, Structure, c_ulong, byref, c_ushort
import time

LBUTTON = 0x01             # Left mouse button
RBUTTON = 0x02               # Right mouse button
middle = 0x04
MIDDLEDOWN = 0x0020 # middle button down 
MIDDLE_UP = 0x0040 # middle button up 
blignyy = 0x05 
dalnyy = 0x06 
x=1
while x<10:
    windll.user32.GetKeyState.restype = c_ushort
    windll.user32.UnregisterHotKey(LBUTTON)
    print(windll.user32.GetKeyState(LBUTTON))
    time.sleep(0.1)
```

Возможно мне нужно не отслеживать кнопки, а нужно перехватить её нажатие или поменять её идентификатор, я новичок, но я уже прошерстил весь гугл по запросам qtpy,tkinter,ctypes блокировка, переназначение , перехват и я нашел только как отключить мышь и клавиатуру полностью, что мне не подходит, тк я использую жесты! *Я в тупике(*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Предыстория

Нашел глобальный хук для питона [тут](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31379169/setting-up-a-windowshook-in-python-ctypes-windows-api) , но появилось ощущение, что мышь лагает и двигается не плавно, поэтому я решил поискать решения на других языках. AutoIT и библиотека mouseonevent.au3, было очень приятно познакомить, но появился баг после которого я терял возможно отправлять действия от нажатий, он возникал, когда я кликал по неактивным окнам. *Видел темы на Stack Overflow с решением моего вопроса на с++, но не смог его запустить из-за проблем со стандартной библиотекой.*

### Решение

Остановился на языке **С#** с библиотекой [LowLevelControls](https://github.com/j3soon/LowLevelControls) , она поддерживает все мои кнопки XButton1, XButton2, левую, правую, горизонтальную и вертикальную прокрутку. Для блокировки стандартного отклика кнопок надо вернуть true! Вот что я поменял в примере **LowLevelControls.Sample2** для блокировки боковых кн:

```
           msHook.MouseDownEvent += (sender, vkCode, x, y, delta, injected) =>
        {
            if ((Keys)vkCode == Keys.XButton1) return true;
            if ((Keys)vkCode == Keys.XButton2) return true;
            return false;
        };
        msHook.MouseUpEvent += (sender, vkCode, x, y, delta, injected) =>
        {
            if ((Keys)vkCode == Keys.XButton1) return true;
            if ((Keys)vkCode == Keys.XButton2) return true;
            return false;
        };
```

### Проблемы и замечания

1. После нажатия левой кнопки мыши консолька и мышь начинают
   виснуть, но так только при активной консоли.
2. При блокировке перемещения курсора msHook.MouseMoveEvent
   координаты мыши X и Y тоже блокируются, хотя на питоне, они менялись
   не смотря на блокировку. Забавно, что курсор можно сдвинуть, но
   через мгновенье он вернётся на место!